# Is there a way to trace when/who installed a google chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

First off, please let me know if this question is out of the scope of Stack Overflow, i've been looking online for answers and haven't found anything.

Today I found an extension called "**Google Apps Training by Boost eLearning**" that is being used within my Google Chrome web browser that states "**your browser is being managed [my company name]**". This extension also states that they have the following permissions:
"**Read and change your data on all google.com sites, gat.boostelearning.com, and gatdev.appspot.com
Read and change your browsing history**"

Per my company, they are saying this extension was never installed by them and furthermore the Macbook that this extension is installed on is my personal laptop.

My question is, can anyone point me in a direction on how to determine:
A.) When this extension was installed
B.) From what source it was installed
C.) The nature of the data that can be read by this extension

See below for MacBook/Chrome Specs

Macbook Specs:
Model Name:   MacBook
Model Identifier: MacBook10,1
Processor Name:   Dual-Core Intel Core m3
Processor Speed:  1.2 GHz
Number of Processors: 1
Total Number of Cores:    2
L2 Cache (per Core):  256 KB
L3 Cache: 4 MB
Hyper-Threading Technology:   Enabled
Memory:   8 GB
Boot ROM Version: 428.0.0.0.0
SMC Version (system): 2.42f13
Serial Number (system):   C02WP15FHH21
Hardware UUID:    B0CCBA78-60C3-5B97-9921-C3D984B879EE

OS:
Catalina version 10.15.6

Chrome:
Version 88.0.4324.182 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Thank you again for any help with this!

Answer (score 0):

I will answer all your questions:

You can watch from the [Google history](https://history.google.com) all things you've done with Google products and if the account you're using is connected on other PC, you are able to see from where and when an extension was installed. By the privacy policy of any extensions that you find on the [Chrome WebStore](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions?hl=it), you can easely discover what type of data the extension collect.

Comment: Signor, Thank you for the quick response! 

Another issue I am running into is:
My company in the past used gmail, for which I had my account synced within google chrome. Currently, we are not using gmail (using outlook) and it looks like my email that was with gmail, is no one active (I can't pull up any history data from it). But I still have this extension installed.

I will keep digging and I again thank you for the info!

Comment: In this case, you should contact your company and ask if they can delete or disable your Gmail old account. But that sounds strange to me, usually every company delete old accounts or restore them. Anyway, you can manage your extensions by going on chrome://extensions/ and uninstall whatever you want.

Comment: Contacted the third-party IT company that handles us..Looks like our gmail account has been deleted but since I never re-synced my new outlook account to google chrome I still see what extensions where installed/used.

While I assume this extension "Google Apps Training by eLearning" is on the up-and-up, I just found it disconcerting that it gave/gives either my company/our IT company/Google so much info without my knowledge